# Using a public virtual derived class outside of its interface

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a situation where I have 2 classes, an interface and an implementation using both classes.

`class A : public virtual Interface<T>`

`class B : public virtual Interface<T>`

`class B` uses `class A` internally, which isn't allowed since `class A` is a derived class of a  public virtual Interface. I get the following error: `error: cannot declare variable ‘a’ to be of abstract type ‘A’` Is there a way to do the following without creating a new class for `A`?

```
class Interface 
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class A : public virtual Interface
{
public:
    void foo(){ }
};

class B : public virtual Interface
{
public:
    void bar()
    {
        A a;
    }
};

class Implementation: public A, public B
{
public:
    Implementation()
    {
    }
};

int main(){
    Implementation impl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It isn't allowed because `A` still has pure virtual functions (`bar`) ... it's nothing to do with it being "declared public virtual".  For `A` to be instantiable ... by anything, it needs to implement `bar`

Comment: Class A isn't "declared public virtual", there is no such thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't instantiate an A because it doesn't implement all the pure virtual functions in Interface.

---

The following works for me.

```
class Interface
{
  virtual void foo() = 0;
  virtual void bar() = 0;

public:
  virtual ~Interface() {}
};

class A : public virtual Interface
{
public:
  void foo() override {}
  void bar() override {}
};

class B : public virtual Interface
{
public:
  void foo() override {}

  void bar() override
  {
    A a;
  }
};

class Implementation : public A, public B
{
public:
  void foo() override { A::foo(); }
  void bar() override { B::bar(); }
};

int main()
{
  Implementation impl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: even if you add all pure virtual functions to `class A`, you get an error: `no unique final overrider for ‘virtual void Interface::bar() in ‘Implemntation’
’`

Comment: I added some code that works for me. Both `A` & `B` need to define both `foo` & `bar`. And since both `A` & `B` define a `foo` and a `bar`, `Implementation` will also need to define them otherwise they will be ambiguous. I just arbitrarily chose which implementation to use.